# Why is the last enum in an array of all enum values created in the enum constructor null?

Tags: java, enums, constructor, initialization

I know that in order to properly iterate over an enum you should do

`for (Days day : Days.values() {}`

I created `static` arrays in my enum Days for weekdays and weekends. I populate them with the appropriate Days values by doing `= new Days[] {SAT, SUN}` in the constructor. These work as intended when I iterate over them.

However I was lost when I created my own static array for all values of Days - added them in the exactly the same way as before. Once iterating over this array the last element to my surprize was `null`. No matter how many elements there where in the Days enum - I started adding more fictional days to test - the result was the same. The "solution" was to make it `final`. However I would like to understand what I was doing wrong.

This tells me initializing the array in the enum constructor is bad. Could my weekdays/weekends arrays suffer from something similar? Is this actually a big no-no? What other things shouldn't one do in an enum constructor? Or more precisely what should it be used for? With the exception of doing things like this

```
enum Days {
  MON("Monday");

  String fullname;

  private Days(String n) {fullname = n};
}
```

Can someone point me to any documentation that could explain this? I might be lacking some captain obvious information about java enums and/or their constructors.

In course of searching for an answer I found `static {}` - would this be good practice in terms of initialization of such static arrays in an enum? Are there any other alternatives?

Edit: since exact code is requested.

```
public enum Days {
  MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;

  public static Days[] weekdays;
  public static Days[] weekend;
  public static Days[] all;

  Days() {
    weekdays = new Days[] {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI};
    weekend = new Days[] {SAT, SUN};
    all = new Days[] {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
  }
}

String s = ""
for (Days d : Days.all) {
  s += d.toString(); //d is null once it reaches the last item 
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Don't describe or paraphrase the errors you get. Post them.

Comment: Can you share the code where said array is initialized?

Comment: Can you post the code that causes the issue (and remove some text from your question [ie. summarize a little])?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile: https://ideone.com/nRyo27. Makoto's answer explains why, but your question suggests that you're running it. It seems like you're running code which doesn't compile (I know some IDEs allow this) or your actual code is different.

Comment: @Radiodef, it actually compiles, using AIDE on android, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public enum Days {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;

    public static Days[] weekdays = {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI};
    public static Days[] weekend = {SAT, SUN};
    public static Days[] all = {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
}
```

Your code didn't compile in my Eclipse IDE. What your code tried to do, is:

- Define an enum with 7 instances `MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN` (that's the first line).
- When any Days instance is created, you populate the three static arrays with specific contents (that's what your constructor does) - here's the problem! When you are instatiating e.g. the first enum instance (which is to become `MON`), the other ones haven't even started their life cycle, and even `MON` is not ready yet (and not yet available under that name). So the arrays get some undefined/empty contents.
- As your enum contains 7 values, you do the array initialization 7 times, each time one more instance is available. The last instantiation is that for SUN. Then the 6 other instances are ready, you overwrite your arrays the seventh time. This time only `SUN` is missing, and that's why you got the last entry still as null.

So, don't reference enum values in constructors of this very enum itself.

By the way, what compiler were you using that didn't flag a compile-time error?

Comment: I am using AIDE IDE on android, apparently it doesn't adhere to java standards because it is android sdk? I don't know the specifics. However, the explanation of why the last item is null is on point, so I am accepting this as the answer to the question in the topic. I would love to hear some advice on how to properly initialize my arrays (even if out of the few options I proposed myself). Thanks.

Comment: The code I gave in my answer works perfectly (at least in desktop Java).

Comment: It does indeed work for me too. If that is best practice (or one of), it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, you're getting burned by [JLS 8.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2).

> **It is a compile-time error to reference a static field of an enum type that is not a constant variable (§4.12.4) from constructors, instance initializer blocks, or instance variable initializer expressions of that type.**

Since the enum values are [themselves `static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), your code is in violation.

While it may seem inefficient, what you *can* do is set up your getter to cache the information about your weekend enums *once*, so you can refer to them later.

```
public Days[] getWeekend() {
    if(null == weekend) {
        weekend = new Days[]{MON, TUE};
    }
    return weekend;
}
```

I leave the issue of handling concurrency problems as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Compile time error though? It compiles fine, it crashes at runtime. I've added some code. Would this still be the cause?

Comment: @Raith:  What version of Java are you running?  Java 8 with IntelliJ refuses to compile this with Error:(11, 42) illegal reference to static field from initializer.

Comment: I am using AIDE IDE for android, it's funny that it doesn't specify what java version it is. I am searching, but it should to be equivalent to 7. I say equivalent because it is actually android sdk. Can't say anything more specific than that. But you are right, this doesn't compile on my desktop with Eclipse and Java 7. My bad.